# "space" Character When Call Widget Or "echo $Content"

Tags: yii

when i render CListView widget, between items printed **spaces (" ")**(showed in follow image), Why? and how can i remove them?
thanks.

[image]

### index view codes:

```
    <div class="borderproject">
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'itemView'=>'_view',
        'template'=>'{items}{pager}',
    )); ?>
    </div>
```

### _view file contents:

```
<div class="projectnum">
    <div class="proimages"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/Images/projects/project1.jpg" class="proimgsize"/></div> 
    <div class="prodetail">
        <div class="protitle"><a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/projects/view?id=<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id);?>" ><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?></a></div> 
        <div class="prodtext"><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->content); ?></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="moredetail"><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/projects/view?id=<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id);?>" >Read more</a></div> 
</div> 
<div class="spproject"></div>
```

### actionIndex

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Projects');
    $this->layout = 'clientSide';
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert file `_view` in `UTF-8 without BOM` encoding